# Servicenow - How to limit the number of records in Legacy:JSON

Tags: json, soap, legacy, servicenow

After reading this
http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Legacy:JSON_Web_Service#getRecords

Following were tried

Base URL: https://my_server.service-now.com/

- /incident.do?JSON&sysparm_action=getRecords&sysparm_force_row_count=3
- /incident.do?JSON&sysparm_action=getRecords&sysparm_query=3
- /incident.do?JSON&sysparm_action=getRecords&sysparm_record_count=3

But every time, returns the all available records for that user.

We are using RetroFit to consume the ServiceNow webservices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, there's no way to limit the legacy JSON processor via request parameters. There is a global property you can set, but that limits rowcount for **every** request.

However, the `JSONProcessor` is just a script include (you can find it by name) that you can modify from within the target instance to *add* this behavior, and this article on the ServiceNow community provides an example:
https://community.servicenow.com/thread/150482